# What makes Chevy better than Ford?

Tags: nascar

[This article](https://www.autoweek.com/racing/nascar/g33242350/20-winningest-cars-in-nascar-cup-history/) states that Chevy has 788 NASCAR wins vs. 696 for Ford as of 2020.

What makes Chevy better than Ford?

Is this a volume stat (in which percentage won would be a better indicator of manufacturer success)? Does this speak to a car's workmanship? Or is this a red-herring such that the driver is more responsible for winning than the car itself?

Comment: I don't believe there's going to be a single reason (or even a small list of reasons) which is going to explain the difference over NASCAR's 75 year history.

Comment: There can be non-opinion reasons that a particular Chevy engine was "better" than a particular Ford engine, but over 75 years of different models?  Maybe they're not actually better but the Chevy's just started more races, or had better drivers for a period of time.  Total number of wins doesn't seem a good basis to begin a comparison to me.

Answer (score 0):

Philip Kendall is correct - there isn't a single reason which will explain this difference. However, there is a reason why there isn't a single such reason: Standardisation.

In 1966, NASCAR started moving away from fully stock cars to cars with modified components. The reasons for this change were for safety reasons and having the specific ability to race. Racecars continued to evolve with safety and having a singular application in mind - to race safely.

For instance, here are specs for a modern-day chassis:

[image: specs for next-gen NASCAR chassis]

Spec sheet provided by [@bobpockrass](https://twitter.com/bobpockrass/status/1390021565287370754).

What you will not see in this spec sheet is the engine. This is where the Ford and Chevy racecars differ. However, this difference isn't enough to ascertain whether racecar drivers won because or despite the manufacturer of the engine.

Pre-1966, the differences among racecar manufacturers may have been more pronounced since stock cars were being used. Now, with heavily standardised racecars sans the engine, this difference is negligible to the naked eye.

Here's a good reference when it comes to talking about the evolution of NASCAR vehicles: https://www.carthrottle.com/post/zdzzmb8/

Comment: Thanks for updating it. I'm still not sure this really answers the question - after all, if the engines are different, that could explain things, no?  It seems like this answer mostly says "it's not the body of the car", but doesn't say what it *is*.